# html, js, css works in jsfiddle but not in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this and it works in jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/h353rdzx/1/)

However I put the following in SharePoint but the counter doesnt show the number. Just the boxes are showing. I even put a alert before the function and it shows the alert. But when I put an alert inside the function then it doesn't pop up. Any idea?

```
<head>
<link href="/SiteAssets/CountDown/CountDown.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var endtime = '4/29/2017';
    function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
      var t = Date.parse('4/29/2017') - Date.parse(new Date());
      var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
      var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
      var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
      var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
      };

    }
alert('test');
    function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
      var clock = document.getElementById(id);
      var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
      var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
      var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
      var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

      function updateClock() {
        var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

        daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
        hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
        minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
        secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

        if (t.total <= 0) {
          clearInterval(timeinterval);
        }
      }

      updateClock();
      var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }

    var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Checked for any errors in the console?

Comment: this clockdiv is being generated by sharePoint? I would suggest you to put the command `debugger;` before this line `var clock = document.getElementById(id);` .. open your DevTools... and check if your var `clock` is being populated

Comment: Getting syntax error at this line <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: var clock = document.getElementById(id); SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'querySelector' of undefined or null reference

Comment: fact that your div `id` isn't with the value `clockdiv` the error is ocurring because js doesn't find your div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked. No matter what I do I could not get the original or suggested code to work in SharePoint.

```
<div id='clockCountDown'></div>
<script>
function countdown(id,endtime){
  var timer=setInterval(function () {
    var t = endtime - new Date();
    if (t>0) {
      var HTML='{0:D2} days {1:HH}:{1:mm}:{1:ss}';
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = String.format(HTML,~~(t/864e5),new Date(t));
    } else {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 1000);
  return(timer);
};
var timer1=countdown('clockCountDown' , new Date('4/29/2017'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do it.

instead of using the `getElementById` use the `getElementsByClassName`...

because I think your Sharepoint is generating a different element id for you div.

See that I also added a `class` attribute to the div `<div id="clockdiv" class="js-clockdiv">` and also changed the call for `initializeClock('js-clockdiv', deadline);`

```js
    var endtime = '4/29/2017';
    function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
      var t = Date.parse('4/29/2017') - Date.parse(new Date());
      var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
      var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
      var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
      var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      return {
      'total': t,
      'days': days,
      'hours': hours,
      'minutes': minutes,
      'seconds': seconds
      };

    }
  alert('test');
    function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
      var clock = document.getElementsByClassName(id)[0];
      var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
      var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
      var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
      var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

      function updateClock() {
      var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

      daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
      hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
      minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
      secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

      if (t.total <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timeinterval);
      }
      }

      updateClock();
      var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }

    var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    initializeClock('js-clockdiv', deadline);
```

```html
    <head>
    <link href="/SiteAssets/CountDown/CountDown.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
    <div id="clockdiv" class="js-clockdiv">
      <div>
        <span class="days"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="hours"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="minutes"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="seconds"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: I am getting this error in the console. 
Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByClassName'

Comment: did you put like this? `var clock = document.getElementsByClassName(id)[0];` did you test the snippet? it's working

Comment: yes sir. https://jsfiddle.net/z577z12q .  I think SharePoint handles this differently.

Comment: copy your sourcecode from your browser after generated by SharePoint and paste in a new jsfiddle ... and put here the link here for me to see...

Comment: not solved yet. sorry, it was weekend and i am barely picking up where I left off. It's impossible to copy the source code from sharepoint rendered page and have jsfiddle to resolve it. thousands of line of code plus lots of links to css and js